# c99 - error: unknown type name ‘pid_t’

Tags: c, c99, pid, c11

I am using Linux (*3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu*), and wrote a simple C program 
about `pid`.

When compile, I got some issue:

- `gcc pid_test.c`, this is fine.
- `gcc -std=c99 pid_test.c` or `gcc -std=c11 pid_test.c`, gives error:

> error: unknown type name ‘pid_t’

**pid_test.c:**

```
// getpid() & getppid() test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pid_test() {
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    pid = getpid();
    ppid = getppid();
    printf("pid: %d, ppid: %d\n", pid, ppid);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, void *argv[]) {
    pid_test();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I did search with Google; people seem have similar issue on Windows, but I am using Linux.  Does `c99` or `c11` remove `pid_t` or move to other header? Or…

Comment: Note that `pid_t` is not a standard C data type, so unless you enable extra types somehow, they won't be visible.  One way to enable them is to use `-std=gnu99` (or `-std=gnu11`); another is to specify a POSIX or X/Open version to use.  I usually use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 800` (or 700 or 600, depending on platform — see [the compilation environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02) for POSIX.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following works for me

```
// getpid() & getppid() test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>    //NOTE: Added
int pid_test() {
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    pid = getpid();
    ppid = getppid();
    printf("pid: %d, ppid: %d\n", pid, ppid);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, void *argv[]) {
    pid_test();
    return 0;
}
```

I found it [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html)

Comment: Yes, the additional header `#include <sys/types.h>` makes it work. So, it seems proper to always add that header when use `pid_t` to get compatibility in future ...

Answer (score 8):

In older Posix standards, `pid_t` was only defined in `<sys/types.h>`, but since Posix.1-2001 (Issue 7) it is also in `<unistd.h>`. However, in order to get definitions in Posix.1-2001, you must define an appropriate [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) before including any standard header file.

So either of the following two sequences will work:

```
// You could use an earlier version number here;
// 700 corresponds to Posix 2008 with XSI extensions
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <unistd.h>
```

or

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```